# set text to a particular text view in grid view

Tags: android, gridview

I have made a resource file gallery_view.xml where I have an image view and a text view on top of the image view. This is just a layout file and I am inflating this layout on a grid view where I will be showing images from phone gallery in each image view.

gallery_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/gvrl"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="108dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/gvivs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop">
            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/check_text"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:onClick="text_view_clicked"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:background="@drawable/checkbox_unchecked"
                android:textSize="12dp">
            </TextView>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When user clicks on a text view, I want to set some text on that particular text view only. For knowing which image view is clicked in the grid view we have OnItemClickListener() method from where we can get its position but how do I know which particular text view has been clicked.

In my gallery_view.xml for the text view I have declared

```
android:onClick="text_view_clicked"
```

And this method is defined in my Import_from_gallery.java class like this

```
 public void text_view_clicked(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(Import_from_gallery.this, "Text View Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

The layout file for Import_from_gallery.java is:

activity_import_from_gallery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Import_from_gallery">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ifgab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="#0097A7">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ifgib1"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp">
        </ImageButton>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pselec"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:maxWidth="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ifgb1"
            android:text="All Photos"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp">
        </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:numColumns="3">
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now how do I know which text view has been clicked amongst many and how do I set text on that particular one.

Thank You

Comment: Just to double-check where you able to add item click listener on the grid view?

Comment: To due with ListView/GridView/RecyclerView, always keep in mind the relationships between DataSet, Adapter and Views. If you directly changed the View, then after scroll up and down, the change will be gone becasue adapter redraw the view according to data in DataSet. So the correct way is to change data (single item or mutliple items), then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to draw the Views. Therefore no need to care if the view is visible or not. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this works for you - from Grid item(View v) you get any child view by Id.

```
gv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        TextView selectedTextView =  v.findViewById(R.id.pselec);
       selectedTextView.setText("WHATEVER_VALUE");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanx Rohit, it's working perfectly. I just want to know one more thing. Suppose I want to set text to a some other text view in the grid view that is not clicked i.e., if user clicks, say on the first text view in the grid view and I want to change the values of text view at positions say 8, 22, 43....like that (considering I already have positions of all text view whose values has to be changed) then how do I do that. Actually I have figured it out, I am using getChildAt(index) but the problem is it doesn't recognises the child which is not in the view, it returns null for them.

Comment: i.e., if only, say 15 text views are visible and in total I have 100 text views, then remaining 85 text views are currently not visible, all those will be visible as I scroll down. So it is returning null for those text views. How can I change their values

Comment: @HandsomeHunk Just to check. So you want to update the text view when you click on it? and the grid view has multiple text views.

Comment: I want to update the text view that is not visible say at 20th position but only 10 are visible. So when I click on text view on position 2nd or 3rd, the text view at 20th position should get updated (which is not currently visible, will be visible only if I scroll down).

Comment: @HandsomeHunk Why do you want to update the 20th position when you click on position 2nd or 3rd? You programmatically scroll to the specific view if you want too.

Comment: Suppose a user has selected 5 random images from the grid view, each image is labelled in numerical order from 1-5. When user again clicks on the image that is labelled say 3 (user wants to deselect that particular image) then the image that is labelled 4 should now be updated and labelled as 3 and the image that is labelled 5 should be updated to 4. And these two images can be anywhere in the grid view, maybe at 20th position maybe at 67th position....this is why I want this functionality